# Pointers questions and confusion

Tags: c, pointers, null

This may be simple but it confuses me.

```
int x;
int *p = NULL;
int *q = &x;
```

What happens when

```
 q = p;   // Address where q points to equals NULL  .
 &x = q;  // I don't think this is possible  .
 *q = 7;  // Value of memory where q is pointing to is 7?  
 *q = &x  // That's just placing the address of x into memory where q points to right?  
 x = NULL;
```

Comment: Is this a sequence of code?  Very different things happen depending on how you combine those statements.

Comment: your comments are right. and `x = NULL` put 0 in x since NULL is a macro

Comment: They're all right. `&x = q` doesn't work because `&x` is not an lvalue. `x = NULL` should be `x = 0`.

Comment: no it's not a sequence; just different lines of code applying on the init.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`q = p;`

Yes. `q` now points to `NULL`, just like `p`.

`&x = q;`

Not legal. You cannot reassign the address of a variable.

`*q = 7;`

Yes, sets the memory of the address where q is pointing to 7. If `q` points to `NULL` then this will cause an error.

`*q = &x;`

<s>Not legal, `q` points to an integer, so you cannot assign an address to it.</s> This is legal, as there is an implicit cast from `int*` (`&x`) to `int` (`*q`), but not very safe. In C++, it is just a plain error. You are right in saying that it places the address of `x` (cast to an `int`) into the memory pointed to by `q`.

Comment: `*q = &x` is legal in C, there is an implicit conversion, but it raises a warning in gcc.

Comment: @ninjalj: Well spotted -- I'm too used to using C++ :-)  I'll fix the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to peters explanation

`*q=&x`

this becomes legal at `*q=(int)&x` .However on a 32 bit OS its good to write `*q=(long)&x`.

```
Note:Some Compilers wont give you an error on  *q=&x
```

`x = NULL;`
x will become 0;